# ¿Cómo aplicar una clase css a un Label cuando un input es seleccionado?

Tags: html, css, css3

¿Cómo aplicar una clase  css a un Label cuando un input es seleccionado?

Quiero cambiar el color del label cuando se este escribiendo en esa caja de texto o es seleccionada

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>
```

Comment: yo creo que para lograrlo sin alterar tu HTML solo va a ser osible usando ademas javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta ahora he hallado dos enfoques para agregar estilo a label con css puro:

Cambiar de orden y usar el selector `+`, que se usa [para elementos consecutivos](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp).

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color: aqua;
}

input:focus+label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
</form>
```

El segundo enfoque implica usar la pseudo-clase focus-within que nos permite seleccionar un padre [si alguno de sus hijos tiene el foco](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within).
Como veras este enfoque esta pensado para labels implicitas y no explicitas como en tu caso.

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color: aqua;
}

label[for=fname]:focus-within {
  color: purple;
}

label[for=lname]:focus-within {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First Name<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"></label>
  <label for="lname">Last Name<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"></label>
</form>
```